# VirtualBox 4.1.12 Ubuntu Host Bridged Networking

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox

## Setup

- Ubuntu Server 11.10 x64
- VirtualBox 4.1.12
- One network adapter eth0 with a static IP address

My /etc/network/interfaces looks like

```
    #Local loopback
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    #Primary Interface
    auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.6
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.0.0.1
```

## Need

Static IP for Ubuntu Host

Static IP for multiple Ubuntu guests

## My attempt

1. Downloaded the .deb for 64bit virtual box
2. `dpkg -i virtualbox.deb`
3. Create a VM and install ubuntu server 11.10 x64 from ISO
4. Set the networking mode to bridged and choose 'eth0' as the interface
5. Fail.

None of the guides I can find for bridged networking work because everything changed since vbox 2

## Edit (Update)

I no longer have this setup running b/c I didn't find an answer. I switched over to an ESXi rig from VMWare. This will prevent me from testing potential answers. I will voluntarily withdraw the question of a mod deems that appropriate, but I do think this is a good question that I'd love to see have an answer for the next poor guy to try this.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your username to the vboxusers group?  Add it with the command below

```
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers username
```

Also check if the various virtualbox kernel modules are already running.

Comment: I did not, and would be curious if that would work. The kernel modules are up and running. Unfortunately I'm no longer running virtual box. I blew the box out in favor of ESXi.